# How to create bootable image of Windows 10, with pre installed softwares in it?

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media

I have windows 10 installed in my laptop. I have lots of installed software, e.g. Microsoft Office, Visual studio, Netbeans etc.

It is possible to create a .iso file of my current operating system, so that If I format my laptop and install windows 10 again from the created .iso file, I don't need to install the software, which I have installed earlier.

Is it possible on linux as well ??

Comment: “It is possible to create a .iso file of my current operating system, so that If I format my laptop and install windows 10 again from the created .iso file, I don't need to install the software, which I have installed earlier.“ - Yes, it is possible.  “Is it possible on linux as well?” - No, there are no tools that exist that would make this easy to do.  You are better off using the Windows tools to do this (it’s how the corporate world does it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create "fresh install ISO with preinstalled Office and other software" however you can create recovery disk by following this guide: [Create Windows recovery](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3140449/windows/everything-you-need-to-know-about-windows-10-recovery-drives.html)

You can also download the actual clean Windows 10 ISO install directly from Microsoft: [Windows 10 Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

Your best option would probably be to clone the whole partition as a backup.

Comment: it actually is possible, this is done every single day in the corporate world.  DISM and sysprep

Comment: can you give more information on how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page from Microsoft. Good luck :)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/audit-mode-overview

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

You can look following tutorials given at microsoft website about building custom images from windows setups, this process is called desktop manufacturing
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-deployment-of-windows-10-for-desktop-editions-get-tools

a lot of tutorials with this respect have been clearly given here
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1977-windows-10-tutorial-index.html

one them which I feel will be relevant in your situation you can find here 
in **part3**  on the link below

***how to create windows 10 iso image for clean in place upgrade repair installation***

This tutorial will show how to create an ISO file of the latest Windows 10 build
Part Three: Custom ISO with pre-installed software, no user accounts
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/72031-create-windows-10-iso-image-existing-installation.html

You will need to have appropriate tools like Windows ADK to do all this
you can download them here
Windows ADK downloads 7.5 GB
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-assessment-deployment-kit

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewADK

a couple of other tutorial links which may help people in a situation like you are

how to create windows 10 image from upgrade files
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/74480-uup-iso-create-bootable-iso-windows-10-build-upgrade-files.html

Install the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK) Technical Reference, with Windows Preinstallation Environment. If you're using the ADK for Windows 10, version 1809, you'll have to download and install the WinPE addon after you install the ADK. Previous versions of the ADK include Windows Preinstallation Environment in the ADK installer.

Use DISM /add-driver to add a device driver to your WinPE image.
Dism /Add-Driver /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /Driver:"C:\SampleDriver\driver.inf"
You can add multiple drivers to an image by using one command, but it's often easier to troubleshoot problems if you add each driver package individually.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize

**what is DISM**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism

For a complete technical description of WIM, see the **Windows Imaging File Format (WIM)** white paper.
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=92227

You can add device drivers to a Windows image before, during, or after you deploy the image. When planning how to add drivers to your Windows deployment, it's important to understand how driver folders are added to the image, how driver ranking affects deployment, and the digital signature requirements for drivers.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/device-drivers-and-deployment-overview

**Add remove drivers to an offline windows image**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image

**Add device drivers to windows during windows setup**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-device-drivers-to-windows-during-windows-setup

To understand **how windows setup works** see windows setup technical reference
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-technical-reference

***Understanding Digital Signature Requirements***
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/device-drivers-and-deployment-overview
64 bit driver guidelines
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=529487
deploy a custom image
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-a-custom-image

create bootable ISO from windows 10 build upgrade files
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/74480-uup-iso-create-bootable-iso-windows-10-build-upgrade-files.html

**Desktop manufacturing**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/

In case you don't want to go through all the steps above and want a simple solution in your situation for example home user who wants an image backup and then restore all the softwares which were previously present on your system 
then you can have a look at free versions of image backup and restore software like
https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree
https://www.clonezilla.org/